# Magento 2 Module Handling Displaying Data proccessed in Controller

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have set up a Magento 2 module to collect some data from a user using a form. When the form is submitted, the controller should process that data, then display the result on another page. I'm having a problem getting the controller to redirect to the results page with the data. Here is what I currently have set up:

Block file
 `vendor\MyModule\Block\Index.php`

```
    public function getManualFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('mamform/index/post');
    }
```

Template file  `vendor\MyModule\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml`

```
<form action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getManualFormAction()) ?>" >
...
</form>
```

Controller file  `vendor\MyModule\Controller\Index\Post.php`

```
public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        var_dump($post);

        // handle and proccess data
       
        // The data processed should be displayed in the Result page
    }
```

The Results Controller `vendor\MyModule\Controller\Index\Result.php`

```
public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

Results template `vendor\MyModule\view\frontend\templates\result.phtml`

```
<h1>Results appears here</h1>
```

Module Routes `vendor\MyModule\etc\frontend\routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="mamform" id="mamform">
            <module name="vendor_MyModule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Result Layout `vendor\MyModule\view\frontend\layout\mamform_index_result.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="vendor\myModule\Block\Index" name="mam_result" template="vendor_myModule::result.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Currently if I visit `/mamform/result` , I can see the template working as expected. How can I now pass the data proccessed in the Post Controller, and display it in the Result page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Redirect result.

In your `Post` controller you can create the redirect object like so:

```php
<?php
public function execute() {
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    // handle and process data
    // The data processed should be displayed in the Result page
    $result = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $result->setPath("path to your result controller", [$post, any_other_params]);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

This will create the redirect result and will call the execute method of whatever controller route you passed as the first param of `setPath` and the array will be passed in with the url.